# Merge Conflicts Cannot see "?" in xcode

Tags: xcode, git, github

I am trying to merge between `Branch 1` and `Branch 2`, so during merge there was a some conflicts but problem i cannot resolve the conflicts because it is not showing `?` arrow in the middle of two branches where i can choose which one i can select right or left. Is this a xcode bug

[image]

Comment: Did you try to use git from the terminal?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes i did it is showing `Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.` . How to fix the conflicts from terminal ?